# (1/1) InvalidStateException in AbstractProvider.php (line 209)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-socialite

I have been looking at all the answers related to this exceptions,  but none of them has got me to a solution.

I have used https://github.com/laravel/socialite to create a Google login for my Laravel application. The user gets logged in, but on page refresh I get the error `(1/1) InvalidStateException in AbstractProvider.php (line 209)`.

I have been stuck for a week. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This could be caused by multiple domains, for example, causing an Invalid State Exception. Try to call the driver with a stateless condition. This may solve the problem (i.e: Google driver):

```
$user = Socialite::driver('google')->stateless()->user();
```

Comment: Thank you @Laerte but I tried using stateless too. No help. Now the error on page refresh is Client error: `POST https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:
{
"error" : "invalid_grant",
"error_description" : "Invalid code."
}

Answer (score 0):

Check the .env file for the APP_URL=http://test.com/
This should be the same URL given in your Facebook Developer account's URL list.